# Hard drive docking station recommendation for old hard drives

Tags: hard-disk, sata, docking-stations

I'm looking for a docking station to read some old hard drives. The hard drives are:

- Maxtor Diamond Plus 9
- Maxtor Diamond VL 40 5400 RPM
- Samsung SP1213C
- WD400BB-32CXA0

Any tips?

Comment: Are they all SATA drives? What's you budget?

Comment: Just doing a quick search on the Maxtor Diamond Plus 9, it's available as both IDE/PATA and SATA.  Please edit your post to indicate which interfaces each one has.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. The plus 9 is Sata

Comment: No, some are IDE and others are SATA. My budget is the lowest I can get away with

Comment: Lowest you can get away with?  Take the cover off the side of your computer and run power and data cables out.

Comment: Good suggestion and I would if I had a computer, but I'm only left with a laptop nowadays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for just for reading some hard drives as you stated in your requirements, a simple universal USB to SATA adapter is more than enough.

These have both IDE and SATA interfaces as well as an external power brick to to provide the power that desktop drives need. Most are able to support both 3.5" (desktop) and 2.5" (laptop) drives.  USB 3.0 ensures fast data transfers.

I have this model in my desk right now:  [UNITEK USB 3.0 to IDE & SATA Converter](http://radnex.us/USB3-IDE-SATA-Adapter)

This one is not the cheapest, but at less than $30, it's very reasonable.  I've bough cheaper and have had them  fail within a short time.  I've been using this one for about 3 years now so it's definitely worth it.

Comment: Just found something similar in the UK UGREEN SATA IDE to USB 3.0 Adapter External Hard Drive Docking Station Enclosure Caddy Reader for 2.5/3.5” HDD SSD CD/DVD ROM CD-RW COMBO DVD-RW DVD-RAM with 12V2A Power Supply for Windows,MacOS,Linux https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B019MF0UC6/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_a3xFCbHNR9382

Comment: Awesome! The USB 3.0 (IMO) is the most important part.  I had a 2.0 version and it was slow, slow slow!